# "Unable to find item" - file exists in cache and I want to open it

Tags: android

I wrote to the cache dir using `getCacheDir()` and am unable to open the file using the user's default program or let him choose which program to open it with, and always get the toast message "Unable to find item", when the File exists, is fully written, can read, etc.

After looking around, I figure that it's in the private area and unless one roots the phone, he won't be able to access it. Fine, I do not want root anyway.

So, where would be a good place to dump that file that I want to get rid of when it's useless? I tried to write to `/data/cache` but it won't work. Where should I write it to?

Comment: have a look over here 'Creating world-readable files is very dangerous, and likely to cause security holes in applications.' http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE

Comment: I am fine with that because the files are meant to be public anyway. Unless there is a way to directly load the file's bytes into the user's preferred application through Android, this is the only way as far as I can tell.

Comment: The *cache dir* is supposed to store private, non-persistent files for your app. It's not meant to be public. To share files with other apps, use one of the [external storage public directories](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#SavingSharedFiles).